# Good and simple reference for studying about ADM mass

Tags: general-relativity, mass, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism

I need a good and simple reference for studying about ADM mass. Can someone introduce me one?

Comment: You can look at Carroll.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87323/2451

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/600567/2451

Comment: Poisson's *A Relativist's Toolkit* or Bojowald's *Canonical Gravity* are great references on this...